# Debug PG::InFailedSqlTransaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, pg

### Some background

`PG::InFailedSqlTransaction` appears when some PG exception is rescued and prevents the transaction from rollback. Simple example:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT nothing FROM nowhere') rescue nil
  binding.pry # <- let's assume we're here
  User.count # raises PG::InFailedSqlTransaction
end
```

The first line inside the transaction silently breaks the transaction and proceeds, any SQL statements after the first line will raise `PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`.

### The question

Assuming we're on the `binding.pry` breakpoint above, are there any ways to debug it and get the initial exception or any other data?
Not quite sure how it is implemented under the hood, but it seems quite possible for PG to cache some metadata about errors.

EDIT: the code above is just an example to demonstrate the general issue, the question is how to get the error in the situation when we cannot easily find the place that rescues the exception

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about: a) What you mean by prevents Rollback, since there is nothing to rollback in your example?; b) What you would like to do? What you are experiencing is as designed when one part of a transaction fails the transaction fails and all further commands should not be executed....

Comment: ...If you want to see the error don't use `rescue nil` instead use a true rescue block. Alternately, at least accoding to the documentation, it appears you can use the `PG::Connection` instance (`ActiveRecord::Base.connection`) to retrieve the most recent error message using the [`error_message`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#error_message-instance_method) method

Comment: @engineersmnky 


a) Rollback is caused by any unhandled exception in an AR transaction, but the first exception which breaks the transaction is ignored by `rescue nil`, so no rollback at this step. Only the next failed command will cause a rollback.


b) I know that it's the correct behavior, what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the initial error that breaks the transaction.

Of course, if I omit `rescue nil` here it will show the error, but it's just a simple example, usually, it's not so obvious in real life :)


Your second comment actually answers my question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @engineersmnky comment, it is possible to get the last error message from the `PG::Connection` instance with `#error_message` method, the instance can be obtained from the ActiveRecord connection: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.error_message`.

If we run the above command from the pry breakpoint in the example from the question, it will return the following message:

```sql
ERROR:  relation "nowhere" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT nothing FROM nowhere
                            ^
```